# How can I run a ruby SAX parser in recovery mode?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax, libxml2

I've got a fairly large XML document that I'd like to scrape some information out of.  It's too big to hold in memory, so I thought a SAX parser would be appropriate.

Unfortunately, whoever produced the XML doc didn't read the spec closely enough, so it contains some illegal XML entities (like `&#8;`).  Other than this, though, it's good as far as I can tell.

For any libraries that rely on libxml, [errors like these will disable future SAX processing unless they are run in recovery mode](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libxml2/libxml2-3/libxml2/parser.c)

```
/*
 * [ WFC: Legal Character ]
 * Characters referred to using character references must match the
 * production for Char. 
 */
if (IS_CHAR(val)) {
    return(val);
} else {
    ctxt->errNo = XML_ERR_INVALID_CHAR;
    if ((ctxt->sax != NULL) && (ctxt->sax->error != NULL))
        ctxt->sax->error(ctxt->userData,
                         "xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value %d\n",
                         val);
    ctxt->wellFormed = 0;
    if (ctxt->recovery == 0) ctxt->disableSAX = 1;
}
return(0);
```

However, both `LibXML::XML::SaxParser` and `Nokogiri::XML::SAX` seem hard-coded to *not* run in recovery mode, so once I run into an illegal entity, parsing pretty much stops (the former throws an error, and the latter just stops showing element start/ends).

Is there a way I can run one of these (or another SAX parser) in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ox](http://ohler.com/ox/) is another ruby XML parser, but it doesn't use `libxml2` as a backend.  [It compares pretty well to Nokogiri speedwise](http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/12b25u/benchmark_ox_vs_nokogiri_and_sax_vs_dom_parsing/).

And it doesn't give a whit about legit XML entities, making running in recovery mode a non-issue.

Adapting the SAX example:

```
require 'stringio'
require 'ox'

class Sample < ::Ox::Sax
  def start_element(name); puts "start: #{name}";        end
  def end_element(name);   puts "end: #{name}";          end
  def attr(name, value);   puts "  #{name} => #{value}"; end
  def text(value);         puts "text #{value}";         end
end

io = StringIO.new(%{
<top name="sample">
  <middle name="second">
    <bottom name="third">&#8;</bottom>
  </middle>
</top>
})

handler = Sample.new()
Ox.sax_parse(handler, io)
# outputs
# start: top
#   name => sample
# start: middle
#   name => second
# start: bottom
#   name => third
# text &#8;
# end: bottom
# end: middle
# end: top
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution I dislike.  Using `Inline::C`, I can create an accessor at runtime for the `recovery` value of the `xmlParserCtxt` wrapped by `Nokogiri::XML::SAX::ParserContext`.

```
unless LIBXML2_HEADERS and File.directory? LIBXML2_HEADERS
  STDERR.puts "Unable to locate libxml2 headers, try setting them manually using the LIBXML2_HEADERS environment variable."
  exit -1
end
class Nokogiri::XML::SAX::ParserContext
  inline do |builder|
    builder.add_compile_flags("-I" + LIBXML2_HEADERS)
    builder.include "<libxml/parser.h>"
    builder.struct_name = 'xmlParserCtxt'
    builder.accessor :recovery, 'int'
  end
end

# ...

Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(NXSDoc.new).parse( File.open("content.rdf.u8", "r:UTF-8") ) do |ctxt|
  ctxt.recovery = 1 # turn recovery mode on
end
```

Comment: Can you create a ticket at https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues for this feature? A test case or script describing usage would be greatly appreciated.